# Problem with align giving runaway argument

Tags: align

When I run the code below I get a "runaway argument" error. I am trying to align in a way similar to the way the code itself is aligned.  I also tried with alignat.  What am I missing?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
      & S &= 1 +  \frac{1}{2} &+ \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} &+ \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{7} &+ \dots \\
      &   &> 1               &+ \frac{3}{3}                             &+ \frac{3}{6}                &+ \dots
  
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think empty lines are allowed in `align`.

Comment: remove the blank line

Comment: if you remove the blank line you get no error but very weird alignment I suspect you want to remove the initial `&`  then use `&&` for the rest (possibly better with `alignat`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is from the blank line, but I suspect you want a different alignment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

original
\begin{align*}
      & S &= 1 +  \frac{1}{2} &+ \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} &+ \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{7} &+ \dots \\
      &   &> 1               &+ \frac{3}{3}                             &+ \frac{3}{6}                &+ \dots
\end{align*}

move \&
\begin{align*}
       S &= 1 +  \frac{1}{2} &&+ \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} &&+ \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{7} &&+ \dots \\
         &> 1               &&+ \frac{3}{3}                             &&+ \frac{3}{6}                &&+ \dots
\end{align*}

alignat
\begin{alignat*}{4}
       S &= 1 +  \frac{1}{2} &&+ \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} &&+ \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{7} &&+ \dots \\
         &> 1               &&+ \frac{3}{3}                             &&+ \frac{3}{6}                &&+ \dots
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```